# Can JPEGs be exported from photoshop without the photoshop file signature?

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg, photoshop, file-type

When I try to upload images to some CMS system I'm using, it fails on some JPEGs and others not. After some searching I found that at the bits and bytes level there is a signature that tells if a file is a JPEG or something else. Apparently JPEGs exported from photoshop have a slightly different signature, and my system seems to fails on them. They are still somewhat JPEGs but more like photoshop JPEGS. If I open and export the file in Gimp for example, it works without a problem.

The one that works starts with: `FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46`

The one that doesn't work: `FF D8 FF ED 00 2C 50 68`

Both files end with: `FF D9`

So my question comes to if there is a way to export those images in photoshop as plain JPEG images?

Comment: Update: manually changing the bytes does work.
 
I changed FF D8 FF ED to FF D8 FF E0, and now it uploads.

Comment: Please share such a file using e.g. Dropbox, Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't shared a Photoshop-created JPEG file and I can't generate one easily, I can only suggest an untested command to rectify the issue.

You should be able to use `exiftool` to remove Photoshop-related stuff from a single image like this:

```
exiftool -photoshop:all= IMAGE.JPG
```

That *may* remove more information than you want, so you could copy the original IPTC data back in like this. This will do all the JPEGs in the current directory:

```
exiftool -photoshop:all= -tagsfromfile @ -iptc:all -ext jpg .
```